# DBase index

Tags: dbase

Is the index value of the first record in a dbf file 0 or 1?  Is the index zero-based?

Answer (score 1):

DBF's are always count based.  I'm not sure what you're after, but given this fact I would have to say 1.   Record 1 = first record in the table, not record 0.  A goto 0 means goto top.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure but this might give you a clue.

http://www.dbase.com/knowledgebase/int/db7_file_fmt.htm

> 1.3.1 Standard Property and Constraint Descriptor Array
>
> > Table field offset - base one. 01 for
> >     the first field in the table, 02 for
> >     the second field, etc. Note: this will
> >     be 0 in the case of a constraint.